# Xampp не видит css

Tags: html, css, xampp

скачал xampp настроил закинул папку с файлами в htdocs открываю файл через локалньный сервер но css не отображается

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для windows рекомендую использовать Open Server Panel,  подобных проблем не возникнет из коробки) или WSL2 если есть опыт с linux.

Comment: в том то и дело что у меня mac